# Connecting a 5 gallon BBQ propane tank to a larger 250 gallon tank

Tags: generator, propane

I need to keep my propane fired generator going during a power outage. My main supply tank is running low and I want to know if it’s possible to connect a smaller BBQ tank to the larger one to keep the generator on.

Comment: In the unlikely event that you happen to have the proper fittings, yes. Generally impractical, though. Jury-rigging with gas is a great way to get a Darwin award.

Comment: Usually a tee and two isolation valves. But will that meet insurance?

Comment: Keep in mind that a 5 gallon tank is unlikely to be able to provide the flow rate needed to a large generator.